# When updating Nuget package in asp.net project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, nuget-package, tinymce-4

I need to update a couple of MS NuGet packages in asp.net project which was developed using Visual Studio. The ones I'm updating are

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream
Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream
Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild
Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild
```

After updating the packages, what is the best way to test if the updates broke anything in the application. In case of Bootstrap and TinyMCE I did some testing to found out that updating them will break the application, so I'm not updating Bootstrap and TinyMCE (from v4 to v6.7). I'm on the fence about updating jQuery because I don't know how to test without testing entire application if jQuery update broke anything in the application. Is there any software or process to see if update will break anything in the application?

Secondly, when publishing project after the NuGet package update, do I need to just copy the related dlls for above packages or entire bin folder?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Ask just one question per post.

Comment: Always be prepared for the possibility that an update may not go as planned. Have a rollback plan in place, so you can quickly revert to the previous package versions and restore your project's backup if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any software or process to see if update will break anything in the application?

Yes, a *comprehensive automated test suite*. If all tests still pass after the  update, you should feel confident to deploy the changes to production - assuming that you trust your test suite. The book [Accelereate](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/accelerate) documents that this is a common trait among high-performance teams.

[Continous Delivery](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/cd) expands on this, but the main point is that this is a very common question (perhaps *the* question) in software development:

*How do I know that the software works?*

And in general, the best we've been able to come up with so far is: *Test it.*

And it's much faster to test the software if the tests are automated.